# Creating "text<tag />text<tag />" content inside a tag in an XDocument file via LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, reflection, linq-to-xml

I am using the `XDocument` class and LINQ to XML to create some simple HTML output, and I stumbled over a problem that I can't seem to solve. Perhaps it isn't even possible at all when using XML.

I have a POCO with a lot of properties, and some of them are named by conventions, so that I use Reflection to iterate through them similar to what follows:

```
List<string> propSuffixes = new List<string>();
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++)
{
  propSuffixes.Add(i.ToString("D2")); // "01", "02", ..., "20"
}

XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
  new XElement("html",
    new XElement("body",
      propSuffixes
        .Select(suffix =>
          (string)typeof(MyPOCO)
          .GetProperty("p" + suffix)
          .GetValue(myPocoInstance))
        .Select(v =>
          new XElement("span", v, new XElement("br"))))));
```

This puts the string values of the 20 properties in their own `<span>` together with a `<br />` tag. But I'd like to have "just" the string values without the span, but still with the `<br />` at the end of each line. That is, like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    propertyValue1<br />
    propertyValue2<br />
    ...
    propertyValue20<br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this even possible, or is this against some XML validation rule? And if it's possible, how can I do it with LINQ? The difficulty for me lies in having to return 2 `object` parameters to the arguments of `new XElement("body",...)`, but also I don't know how to pass just that `string` before the `<br />` to the arguments without raising some errors.

Do you know of any way to accomplish my goal, or alternatively to accomplish a similar layout (perhaps I could use `<p>` instead of `string` plus `<br />`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to get the `<br />` at the end of the line, but you can certainly break up text and tags, like so:

```
XElement root = new XElement("root");
root.Add(
    new XText("Text"), 
    new XElement("tag"),
    new XText("Text"), 
    new XElement("tag"), 
    new XText("Text"));
```